# Airborne Access to Narnia

Tags: teleportation, dimensions

Edit: edits inspired by @TzeraFNX's suggestion

Suppose we have a pocket dimension or alternate dimension that's accessed a bit like Narnia, by having *very subtle* portals in various secluded places (remote rural forest roads, the inside of a large coat closet, etc) that are passed through when moving in a specific direction, in a specific context, etc, while in other cases, one passes by the portal without noticing anything unusual.

In particular, observers who aren't entering the portal should not be able to see any objects entering the portal (rather, they enter a secluded space and mysteriously disappear when nobody is watching them) and *nobody* should ever see a clear portal boundary or surface (the exact opposite of, say, a stargate ring or the blue and orange boundaries in Valve's Portal and Portal 2), or see the enchanted world from a standpoint that's completely in the normal world.

By this method it's possible to allow personnel and vehicle access to our enchanted land without people noticing what's up. But aircraft access is a bit harder, unless you resort to landing them and then taxiing or towing them along the aforementioned secluded forest road, which I don't (and which tends to subject itself to nosy people looking at aerial photographs).

Does anybody have a clear idea of what we want to do here?

Comment: "*Does anybody have a clear idea of what we want to do here?*" honestly no. What are you asking? Do you *only* have land portals (or near the ground, at least) but want to transfer airplanes?

Comment: We provide solution to well defined problems. You seem to have an unclear problem, too. Please clarify.

Comment: Are you asking how to get an aircraft into Narnia?  I have to VTC until the question is edited to be more clear on what you are asking.

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit based on @TzeraFNX's rejected edit suggestion (which itself made too many assumptions about what I'm asking for me to directly adopt it).

Answer (score 4):

if you want airborne access to a Narnia-type world, then your subtle portals could extend upwards over a remote rural road. It would only be a matter of an aircraft flying in the right direction, at the right airspeed, and at the right altitude above, for example, the remote rural road.

There could be portals that exist at an altitude above the ground  of suitable locations. These could only be accessible by aircraft.

By and large, helicopters might be preferred type of aircraft used for accessing Narnias. They can remain airborne at lower speeds. Also, Narnia itself seems to be somewhat airport or airfield free. Landing a fixed wing aircraft in Narnia might have its problems. Flying boats, seaplanes, possibly hang gliders, and VTOL aircraft are also suitable candidates for Narnia-accessing aircraft.

Hot air balloons are another option, but in that case the portals would have to have large aperture diameters.

in conclusion, Narnias can be accessed via portals that either extend above ground level to suitably high altitudes (but not too high otherwise airliners might get lost) and using the appropriate type of aircraft like helicopters,  aircraft capable of landing or taking off from bodies of water, even hot air balloons, or hang gliders.